# Unable to pull certain text element off of a website with puppeteer. Wondering why this is and how to work around it

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to build a web scraper to scrape my venmo page for a project. I can get puppeteer to open the page and navigate to my page, as well as log in by storing chrome user data, but I am trying to pull the time that I was sent money and the value of that transaction. Specifically only my most recent transaction.

I know that the scraper works, and returns values to me because I created a new document.querySelector that just scrapes my name off of the top of the site. When I run the script without .innerHTML or .innerText I get no errors thrown but the two values I'm looking for, not my name, return null, but my name is returned to me. When I add .innerHTML or .innerText I get an error thrown at me

```
valuation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4:58
```

I have run my elements in the console of the inspect element and they are both returned to me so I'm having trouble understanding why the console on the webpage will return them but my script will not. It isn't just the Chromium window that's created with puppeteer messing me up either because I have entered the document.querySelector in that console too and it returns with what it is supposed to.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//sets url to nav to 
const url = 'https://venmo.com/user';

(async () =>  {

//open broswer window and opens a new page
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ["--user- 
data-dir=./Google/Chrome/User Data/"]}); 
try{
const page = await browser.newPage();

//sets view to 1920x1080
await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720});

//navigates to the specified url
await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

//playing with wait states incase the document wasnt loading correctly
await page.waitFor(1000);

//function for evaluating the webpage
const  data = await page.evaluate(() => {

    let amount =  
    document.querySelector('span.bold.medium.green').innerHTML
    let timePayed = document.querySelector('a.grey_link').innerHTML

    //this function prints my name 
    let test = document.querySelector('span.bold').innerHTML

    return { 
    amount,
    timePayed,
    test
    }
}); 


//displays the data scraped
 console.log(data);
}
catch(err) {
     console.error(err.message);
}


debugger;

await browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason you're using Puppeteer?  Is that the required framework for your project, or can you use others?

Comment: The page most probably hasn't fully loaded when you're scraping it. Try to page.waitFor( 'span.bold.medium.green' ) instead of page.waitFor(1000).

Comment: It is not a requirement I just was not sure what to use. Would anything else work better?